# How to separate row value into different column in sql?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a table with columns col1, col2, col3 and value

```
col1  col2 col3
100    1    1
200    1    2
250    1    2  
300    1    3
100    2    1
450    2    2
300    2    3
```

How can i get this result whit sql

```
col1    col2   col3   col4
100      1       100     2
200      1       450     2
250      1        -      - 
300      1       300     2
```

Can someone route me to some examples or solutions how to solve this problem?

Comment: are you looking for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx?

Comment: @DevN00B: This is Firebird, not SQLServer.

Comment: @user2531567 Describe what rules decide which column something ends up in, and what decides that `(100, 1)` is joined up with `(400, 2)`?

Comment: What is the logic of "column creation"? Is it the value of `col2`, ie you want one pair of columns for each differnet value of `col2`?

Comment: Ok col3 decide how to row be joined

Comment: Why is `450 2 2` joined to `200 1 2`, rather than `250 1 2`?

Comment: Sum 200 1 2 and 250 1 2 = 450 2 2

Comment: if a use join itself table whit aliases in result table in col3 after 450 i have 450 too.it is posible to have null.

Comment: I removed the `delphi` tag, as this question has absolutely nothing to do with Delphi. It's strictly a Firebird SQL question. Please use tags that apply to your question, and don't use those that don't. Using the tags properly helps keep questions in proper categories, and gets them to the attention of people who can answer them. Thanks.

Comment: @user2531567 I still don't follow the logic here. In the second table, what's Col2? And does the first table also contain summary values that appear in the second table? If not, what about the 460 2 2 row? I believe what you're probably looking for is a window function, which doesn't exist in Firebird (or Interbase, MySQL or SQLite). You're probably going to need to use multiple select statements, but first you need to be clearer on what these tables represent and what calculation you're trying to perform.

Comment: Ok.Forget about Col2 and Col4 in Second table.I need result only Col1 and Col3.In first table Col1 must be separeted.Col2 says how value in col1 must be separeted.Col3 decide how value must be joined.The problem is in trid row in col3 must have null.If I use join itselfs table whit aliases in trid row in col3 result is 450 not null.

Comment: @alcalde Firebird 3.0 (the alpha should be out in somewhere in the next few weeks) introduces window functions.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel The information about Firebird 3.0 is deceptive. There has been talk of Firebird 3.0 being released since 2005! Firebird 3.0 Alpha was already released in the summer of 2012. At the start of 2013 they changed the roadmap to say that it was coming "Q1 2013" - done! Then at the start of April they changed the roadmap again to read that it "was coming" Q2 2013. The reality is it's been a year since the alpha release and there's been nothing else since. With 3.0 several years behind, I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for window functions (or anything else) for Firebird.

Comment: @alcalde There has not been a Firebird 3 alpha release before, but it is being prepared now. It has indeed taken a long time, however Firebird 2.5 was an intermediate release that contained a lot of improvements initially announced for Firebird 3.

Comment: @Mark I apologize on something. I thought Alpha was released in 2012 but this is not the case. However, using Archive.org I checked old roadmap pages and it was originally promised for Q2 2012. Then Q3 2012. Then Q1 2013. Now Q2 2013. Since it's July, it's actually Q3 2013 now. :-( Firebird 2.5 came out in 2010. When/if Firebird 3 finally is released it's still going to be way behind competitors since its going to be at where it planned to be in 2005/6. It's a nice, fast database but I fear it may have fallen too far behind at this point, has few developers, no major commercial support, etc.